# Film/miniseries shown in late 1980s featuring domes, white suits with red on them, and two factions

Tags: story-identification, movie

I watched this seemingly older movie probably in 1988-1991 in Kentucky in the library at school.

What I recall is a futuristic setting - perhaps in a desert. There were domes, and I recall white suits with red on them. There were two factions - good guys (possibly from the past/Earth) and bad guys who were out to get them.

I know this is vague but I can’t think of what this is to save my life. I’ve looked at other posts in hopes of figuring it out, but no luck.

Comment: [Capricorn One](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0077294)? There is really very little information to go with in your question. Most movies have bad guys and good guys.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: Do you know if this was an educational programme? It probably was if it was shown in a school library, but schools do sometimes show content that wasn't intended as educational (case in point, [Blackadder Goes Forth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blackadder_Goes_Forth) [series finale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goodbyeee) in history classes about WW1)

Answer (score 4):

Is it *[Tomes and Talismans](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Series/TomesAndTalismans)*? We watched this in the library in the late '80s in Maryland. I actually missed the final episode because I got into a fight with Chris Carroll on the way to the library.

> In 2123 humanity is evacuating Earth for the White Crystal Solar System, due to pollution and an attack carried out by the nefarious Wiper race, a group of aliens that are determined to interfere with communication and data technology. The One World Order is preparing a complete library of all Human knowledge which is hidden underground. A desperate search for an important missing volume of recent history begins in the library in the outskirts of the city. The library team leader, Ms. Bookhart, is stranded in her bookmobile and is suddenly metabolically suspended for 100 years by a being known only as "The Universal Being".
>
> She awakens in a world under the control of the Wipers having been discovered and awoken by four children—Aphos, Abakas, Varian, and Lidar—members of another group of pacifistic, tech-savvy extraterrestrials known as "The Users". The children, along with Ms. Bookhart, rediscover the hidden library, and in the course of the series she teaches them how to use it. When the Wipers lay siege to the User base with an entrapping shield and plan an attack, the kids and Ms. Bookhart (later assisted by Colonel Holon, the father of Aphos and Abakas) must decipher a cryptic message from the Universal Being to find a way to defeat the Wipers and save their people. Yes, the world is saved through mastery of library science.

### Episode 1

Comment: Can you specifically address why you think this is what the asker is looking for?

Comment: @Jack There are various factors which match, some of which you can tell from the[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tomes_%26_Talismans) description. For "futuristic setting" - it starts off in the late 21st century, then later skips 100 years into the future. There were good guy and bad guy factions who both looked human - the good guys enlisted the help of the last surviving human. In the video posted, you can see red-orange uniforms with white on them, so a sort of color-flip of the uniforms OP remembers. It's a library-themed educational series from 1986, so OP could plausibly 1/

Comment: have seen a video or rerun of it screened in a school library. I can't find enough video footage to comment on the "dome" - though there was a base under a forcefield, perhaps that was the dome? However, not everything matches. The desert setting is contradicted by [TVTropes](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Series/TomesAndTalismans), which says that both the pre-and post-time-skip episodes are set in a wooded area of Pennsylvania, "near a small town ... still has regular highways and roads, even railroad tracks". And the good guy uniforms after the timeskip weren't red-and-white.

Comment: FWIW, I think this probably is the series OP was asking about. I think some streaming service has it in the US, I wonder if it's accessible from the UK?